# How to use Message Box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show a message box to the user where they can select either YES or NO from the message box; if they select Yes i want to call some function and if they select NO then i want to call another function.  That is not what i have now in my my code please help.  thanks 
Here is my code:

```
 protected void TEST()
    {
        string ID= ddlPr.SelectedValue;
        string PRACTICE_TYPE = DDL_TYPE.SelectedValue;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [DA2].[QPMS].[QPMS_RESPONSE] WHERE ID=@ID";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);             
                con.Open();
                int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result >=1)

                {
                    //if the user selects YES i want to call some function if user             selects No then i want to call another function.
                    string myscript = "alert ('message');";
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", myscript, true);                    

                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: msgbox is available only in winform. In asp.net you can have JS confirm box.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show

Comment: this will be useful : http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Style="position: static" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="Button2_Click" Style="position: static; display: none" Text="Ok" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="Button5_Click" Style="position: static; display: none" Text="Cancel" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function confirmProcess()
            {
                if (confirm('are you sure to continue?'))
                {
                   //if you are missing this, always use ClientID to get reference to button //control when used with master pages
                    document.getElementById('<%=Button2.ClientID%>').click();
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('<%=Button5.ClientID%>').click();
                }
                
    
            }
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
```

**//code-behind**

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Clicked Canceled");
}


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Clicked OK");
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String csname = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname))
    {
        String cstext = "confirmProcess();";
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, cstext, true);
    }
}
```

[ASP.Net Message Box Alert Display](http://forums.asp.net/t/1459501.aspx?Displaying+a+Messagebox+with+Ok+Cancel+button+using+C+in+web+application)

Comment: i want the user to have Yes or No option in the message box so when they select Yes the code will a function and etc

Comment: @moe check modified answer

Comment: thanks but i am not using any button, i am using a method that is called Test() and i want to place the message box alert inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

I use this currently in all of my Web Applications I created a Static Method that I can call one of the 2 overloaded Methods this works 100% I just tested to confirm

```
    public static void ShowClientMessageDlg(string msg, string aValue, string redirect = "")
    {
        string msgFormat;
        msgFormat = string.Format(" {0}", aValue);
        msg = msg + msgFormat;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Joins a String of Values to create a Message Box
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg"></param>
    /// <param name="aValue"></param>
    /// <param name="redirect"></param>
    public static void ShowClientMessageDlg(string msg, List<string> aValue, string redirect = "")
    {
        string msgFormat;
        msgFormat = string.Format(" {0}", string.Join<string>(", ", aValue.ToArray()));
        msg = msg + msgFormat;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
    }
```

Comment: i am getting a compiler error when i paste this code, one of error is that it does not like this: List<string>

Comment: did you add `using System.Linq;` to your class header also you need to know how to use static methods I created my own class Inherited from webpage like this `public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {}' and that's where the `Static Method` resides also dod you know how to call the method that was created..? if not I can send you an example

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Rahul in the comments, a messagebox is only available in winforms.  Also, the `javascript alert` will only display a message.  You can't execute different code blocks based on the end user response.  What you want is a confirm dialog box.  There's a simple example [here.](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm)

From link:

```html
<input type=button value="Try it now" 
onClick="if(confirm('Format the hard disk?'))
alert('You are very brave!');
else alert('A wise decision!')">
```

For asp, just create a different function to call rather than the alert.

If you wanted an alternative to javascript you could also make use of the [AjaxToolkit ConfirmButton Extender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx).   It's based on a button click so you would have to "cheat" a little to use it.  Call the `MyButton.Click()` method to activate the confirm dialog.  You probably could hide the button by setting `Display: none;`.

Overall, I think the javascript is still probably your best option.

Comment: but i am not using any button, i want to be able to call the java from a method in code behind.